# Convert integers to a Byte array VB.net

Tags: vb.net, stream, arrays

I have the following Java code working as expected, to convert some numbers to an array of Bytes before writing to a stream.

```
byte[] var1 = new byte[]{
    (byte)-95,
    (byte)(240 / 256 / 256 % 256),
    (byte)(240 / 256 % 256),
    (byte)(240 % 256),
    (byte)0
};
```

I need to write the same in VB .net
I tried the following code in VB .net, but no success.

```
Dim var1(4) As Byte
    var1(0) = Byte.Parse(-95)
    var1(1) = Byte.Parse(240 / 256 / 256 Mod 256)
    var1(2) = Byte.Parse(240 / 256 Mod 256)
    var1(3) = Byte.Parse(240 Mod 256)
    var1(4) = Byte.Parse(0)
```

Am I doing it wrong.? How to get it done properly..

Thank you.

Comment: What does `to no avail` mean? What was the error or output? Also note that Byte.Parse parses a string, not an integer, as [noted in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Byte.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For "-95", it halted with an exception, that -95 is too small for Byte, and "240 / 256 / 256 Mod 256" didn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert an integer *(32 bit (4 byte))* to a byte array using the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
Dim result As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(-95I)

Dim b1 As Byte = result(0) '161
Dim b2 As Byte = result(1) '255
Dim b3 As Byte = result(2) '255
Dim b4 As Byte = result(3) '255
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''' <summary>
''' Convert integer to user byte array w/o any allocations.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="int">Integer</param>
''' <param name="DestinationBuffer">Byte array. Length must be greater then 3</param>
''' <param name="DestinationOffset">Position to write in the destination array</param>
<Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>
Public Overloads Shared Sub GetBytes(Int32 As Integer, ByRef DestinationBuffer As Byte(), DestinationOffset As Integer)
    DestinationBuffer(DestinationOffset + 0) = CByte(Int32 And &HFF)
    DestinationBuffer(DestinationOffset + 1) = CByte(Int32 >> 8 And &HFF)
    DestinationBuffer(DestinationOffset + 2) = CByte(Int32 >> 16 And &HFF)
    DestinationBuffer(DestinationOffset + 3) = CByte(Int32 >> 24 And &HFF)
End Sub
```