# vb.net sql parameter incorrect syntax near 'value'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm new here, I'm trying to convert an integer into varbinary to insert into an already made SQL table. I've included the code, I get incorrect syntax near "523641" which is the `HOUSE_ID` I am trying to convert.

I also converted the int to byte array and added a parameter to the command but same result

```vb
Dim varbin As String = " convert(varbinary, '" & houseid & "')"
obj = objCon.CreateCommand()
strSQL = "insert into " & tbl & " (hello, HOUSE_ID, world) VALUES ('" & hello & "','" & varbin & "','" & world & "')"
obj.CommandText = strSQL
obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Expected result is putting that 523641 into the `varbinary(50)` column.

Comment: can you show the ddl of your table?

Comment: You are putting single quotes around the `varbin` variable, which itself is a call to `CONVERT`.  But rather than making that change, you should seriously look into using a prepared statement.

Comment: table name: 
tbl

columns:
hello: varchar(50), null
HOUSE_ID: varbinary(50), null
world: varchar(50), null 

i'm giving an example cause the table is too big

what if you have an int and you want to insert it in an sql column which is varbinary?

Comment: Print out your `strSQL` string to the console, and you should immediately see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to store an integer in a varbinary column but you can use [`BitConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319726/convert-integers-to-a-byte-array-vb-net) along with a parameterized query. Always use parameters instead of string concatenation for values that vary by execution as parameters have a number of benefits for security, performance, and ease of use.

```
Dim varbin As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(houseid)
obj = objCon.CreateCommand()
strSQL = "insert into " & tbl & " (hello, HOUSE_ID, world) VALUES (@hello, @varbin, @world);"
obj.Parameters.Add("@hello", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = hello
obj.Parameters.Add("@varbin", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 50).Value = varbin
obj.Parameters.Add("@world", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = world
obj.CommandText = strSQL
obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: would like to make both answers useful but i can't since i'm new, but thank you both and have a great day :)

Comment: @DCON, you should have enough cred to mark answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).