# How to send bytes through RS-232C serial?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, vb6, serial-communication, vb6-migration

Because `vb.net` no longer accepts `ChrB` for communication via RS-232C. In older days (`vb6`), one can use code (assuming we paste `comRs` `MSComm` control on the form) like the below:

```
Public Sub M__RsSb(Sb As Integer)
  Dim b() As Byte
  b = ChrB(Sb)
  comRs.Output = b
End Sub
```

I think that one must try to send bytes instead of `Sb` above in the case of the new Visual Basic (`vb.net`). First, one must know the corresponding hex value for `Sb`. For example, let us assume this is `&HFE`. So, the migration (from `vb6` to `vb.net`) will be like the below:

```
Public Sub M__RsSb(ByVal Sb As Byte())
  Dim b As Byte() = {&HFE}
  SerialPort.Write(b,0,b.Length)
End Sub
```

But, I think it is correct. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: you can use [Convert.ToByte(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToByte_System_Int32_).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integers to a Byte array VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319726/convert-integers-to-a-byte-array-vb-net)

Comment: `ChrB()` doen't do what you seem to think it does.  As used above, it fails if `Sb` is over 255.  When it works, it produces a Variant String of one byte, and then that monster is converted to a Byte array above.  You may as well just `ReDim B(0):B(0) = Sb` and call it good.  Either one will overflow if `Sb` isn't between 0 and 255.