# Convert Byte to Byte() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have got a `Long` variable (`FileLen`) which I converted to `Byte` via `CByte()`; however for use I need it it in the `Byte()` format.

Currently I have:

> `Dim Bytes As Byte = CByte(FileLen(dlgSave.FileName))`

> `Dim BytesFin As Byte() = Convert.ToByte(Bytes)`

The latter line here shows the error `Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'`

I have also tried `Dim BytesFin() As Byte = Convert.ToByte(Bytes)`

The code is being used in the below function: (I got this off a website, the address of which I cannot recall)

```vb
Shared Function SaveFile(ByVal FileName As String, ByRef Buffer() As Byte, ByVal OverWrite As Boolean) As Boolean
    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(FileName) Then
            If OverWrite Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(FileName)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(FileName, Buffer, False)
                Return True
            Else
                'File exists - don't save
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(FileName, Buffer, False)
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

It is called here:

```vb
SaveFile(dlgSave.FileName, Bytes, True)
```

Comment: What you are doing is extracting only the lowest byte of the file length and discarding the information in the other high bytes. Is that okay? Isn't this article what you really want to do? [Convert integers to a Byte array VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23319726/9014308)

Comment: Instead of telling us what code you want to write, how about you explain what you actually want to achieve? What exactly is this `Byte` array supposed to contain once you're done? A `Long` is a 64-bit number so that's 8 bytes. Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want an array containing those 8 bytes?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, yes, I do believe I need an array - It is taken within a function to save as GIF.

Comment: Maybe you need the binary data of the file? Just guessing.

Comment: @Magnus That's an idea. I'm rather a novice at this area of VB - how would I do that?

Comment: @WHerschel what do you intend to do with the array?

Comment: @Magnus See above code

Comment: @kunif This does not seem to work, don't know if I should change Byte to Double, or how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you want to read the content of the file. Assuming `dlgSave.FileName` is the full path to the file you can do:

```
Dim file As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(dlgSave.FileName)
```

Or you might need to use another property on `dlgSave`.