# Compile PNG images to an animated GIF

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a VB.NET application in which the user should be able to save a GIF with a custom text overlay. Currently I can save the GIF, but the text (which does appear when saving PNG images) is not visible.

I have this code currently:

```vb
File.Copy(img.ImageLocation, "temp.gif")
Timer1.Start()
While Timer1.Enabled
    'wait for timer to complete
End While
File.Delete("temp.gif")
```

And:

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = saver.Panel1.Bounds
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(saver.Panel1.Width, saver.Panel1.Height)

    bounds.X = 0
    bounds.Y = 0

    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("temp.gif")
        While line IsNot Nothing
            saver.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, bounds)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(dlgSave.FileName, MyUtilities.BitmapToByteArray(bmp), True)
        End While
        Timer1.Stop()
    Next
End Sub
```

This appears to freeze the application; previous code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006822/convert-byte-to-byte-in-vb-net/78007695#78007695) will save only the GIF *sans* the text.

Comment: `For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("temp.gif")`? What the heck is that? -- In any case, you're just generating a Bitmap, you're not attempting to create a GIF image, which, BTW, you cannot do with these methods